# How to compute an integral that involves random variable.

Tags: calculus, random-variables

Given the following first order ODE,

$$
\dot{x}(t) = F(t)x(t) + G(t)w(t) + L(t)u(t)
$$

According the book I'm reading, the solution is

$$
x(t) = \Phi(t,t_o)x(t_o) + \int_{t_o}^{t} \Phi(t,\tau) G(\tau)w(\tau) \ d\tau \  \ + \int_{t_o}^{t} \Phi(t,\tau) L(\tau)u(\tau) \ d\tau
$$

where $w(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$. My question is how can I perform the integral of the second term? Also, in which calculus field this kind of problems are covered? Calculus textbooks don't cover performing integrals over random variables.

Comment: What is $\Phi$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin   $\Phi$ is the transition matrix.